# Converting to uppercase in C++

Tags: c++, string, uppercase, toupper

Let's say you have:

```
const char * something = "m";
```

How would one make this uppercase, using toupper (or something else, if applicable)?

I want to use a `char *` instead of a `string` (I can use a string, but then I have to use `str.c_str()`).

So, how can I make `char * something = "m";` contain `"M"`?

Comment: No, use `std::string`. And pick a language: there is no such thing as "C/C++".

Comment: And what do you want to do with `char something[] = "\xEF\xAC\x83";`? (i.e. ﬃ)

Answer (score 8):

I find you choice of C strings disturbing.. but anyway.

You can't change a string literal (`char *something`). Try an array:

```
char something[] = "m";
something[0] = toupper(something[0]);
```

To change an entire string:

```
char something[] = "hello";
char *p = something;

while (*p) {
    *p = toupper(*p);
    p++;
}
```

Comment: It says: initializer fails to determine size of 'input'          const char * input = "m";
char something[] = input;
something[0] = toupper(something[0]);
char *p = something;

Comment: @John That's not what I said :-) Read the answer again. Even better, look at Kerreks answer.

Comment: `p` is extraneous here -- use `something` only and the example will be much clearer IMO.

Comment: @ildjarn But I can't increment it. I would have to use a separate iterator.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I know. It's usually implemented with macros (I've seen it somewhere in Plauger) so passing it the wrong thing is undefined behavior. Edit my post if you like, I'll accept your edit.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the same algorithmic approach that you know for `std::string` for raw arrays:

```
char s[] = "hello world";
std::transform(s, s + std::strlen(s), s, static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper));
```

You cannot do this for immutable string literals (like `const char * s = "hello world;"`) for obvious reasons, so you won't get around an additional allocation/copy for that.

*Update:* As Ildjarn says in the comment, it's important to note that string literals are *always* read-only, even though for historical reasons you are allowed to bind them to a pointer-to-mutable, like `char * s = "hello world";`. Any decent C++ compiler should slap you in the face if you attempt this, but it *is* valid C++ -- but any attempt to actually *modify* any element of `s` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I think it may be worth explaining more in-depth why `char * s = "hello world;"`, sans `const`, is also immutable -- this is a primary hangup for beginners.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Good point; you should probably use the version of `toupper` that comes with `<locale>` for a more general solution.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Nobody can keep up with zose crazy Germans :-) Now they *do* have a [capital SZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_ß), but it's not representable by a `char`... *sigh*

Answer (score 5):

As explained in the very famous C book - `The C Programming Language` by `Kernighan & Ritchie` in section `5.5 Character Pointers and Functions`,

```
char amessage[] = "now is the time";    /* an array */
char *pmessage = "now is the time";     /* a pointer */

`amessage` is an array, just big enough to hold the 
sequence of characters and `'\0'` that initializes it. 
Individual characters within the array may be changed 
but `amessage` will always refer to the same storage. 
On the other hand, `pmessage` is a pointer, initialized 
to point to a string constant; the pointer may subsequently 
be modified to point elsewhere, but the result is undefined
if you try to modify the string contents.
```

OTOH, in C, to convert to upper case letters, you can use the following program as a reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    char str[]="Test String.\n";
    char c;

    while (str[i]) {
        c=str[i];
        putchar(toupper(c));
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    locale loc;

    string str="Test String.\n";

    for (size_t i=0; i<str.length(); ++i)
        cout << toupper(str[i],loc);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Adding pointer version (as requested by @John) for the C version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    char str[]="Test String.\n";
    char *ptr = str;

    while (*ptr) {
        putchar(toupper(*ptr));
        ptr++;  
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @John could you please elaborate your question?! You mean, how to have a pointer point to an array?

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj, when you pass a `char` to the C toupper and other functions taking a character in an `int`, it must be first cast to an unsigned char and then to an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert C-string to std::string and then use boost::to_upper to change string in place or boost::to_upper_copy to create upper case copy of the string. Here is the code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp>

int main ()
{
  char const * s = "Test String.\n";
  std::string str(s);

  std::cout << boost::to_upper_copy(str).c_str() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <ctype.h>

char test[] = "m";

std::transform(std::begin(test), std::end(test), std::begin(test), ::topper);
```

This applies the `::toupper` function to character of the string. This is the `::toupper` function in the global namespace that comes from C. `std::toupper` has multiple overloads and `::toupper` looks more elegant than `static_cast<int (*)(int)>(&std::toupper)`.