# invalid initializer

Tags: c++

This code keep saying :  error: invalid initializer

```
char * ss = "hello world";
char s[10] = ss;
std::transform(s, s + std::strlen(s), s, static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper));
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Perspective: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693990/converting-to-uppercase-in-c

Comment: Posted new so people can see it clean

Comment: I didn't say it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Your initializer of the array with a C string is invalid. The good news is that you do not need it at all:

```
char * ss = "hello world";
char s[12];
std::transform(ss, ss + std::strlen(ss)+1, s, static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper));
cerr << s << endl;
```

Note that I padded your `s` array with an extra element for the terminating zero.

Comment: @SethCarnegie You are correct - I just fixed it half a minute ago. My counting is a bit rusty this morning (not surprising, given it's the first day of the new year :)

Answer (score 1):

```
char s[10] = ss;
```

This tries to set an array's value equal to a pointer, which doesn't make any sense. Also, ten bytes isn't enough (there's a terminating zero byte on the end of a C-style string). Try:

```
char s[20];
strcpy(s, ss);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a pointer to an array because you can't assign anything to arrays but initialiser lists. You need to copy the characters from `ss` to `s`. Also, an array of size 10 is too small to hold `"hello world"`. Example:

```
char * ss = "hello world";
char s[12] = {}; // fill s with 0s

strncpy(s, ss, 11); // copy characters from ss to s
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
char s[] = "hello world"; // create an array on the stack, and fill it with
                          // "hello world". Note that we left out the size because
                          // the compiler can tell how big to make it

                          // this also lets us operate on the array instead of
                          // having to make a copy

std::transform(s, s + sizeof(s) - 1, s, static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array assignment is illegal and, in the case of your code, isn't needed in the first place.

```
const char * ss = "hello world";
char s[12];
std::transform(ss, ss + std::strlen(ss)+1, s, static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::toupper));
```